# How to get input with char instead of integer in c sharp

Tags: c#, list, input, clist

**Hey there.**

I am trying to learn C sharp by myself but i have a problem about getting input as an character.
My code part is :

```
    var foodTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foodTypeMap["1"] = "Soups";
    foodTypeMap["2"] = "Vegetables";
    foodTypeMap["3"] = "Mains";
    foodTypeMap["4"] = "Deserts";
    ...
    ...
    string fType = Console.ReadLine();
    string dishType = " ";
    //if else statements here.. etc
    dishType = foodTypeMap[fType];
```

by this way i can get the fType as an integer and initialize the dishType by that. I want to get the choices by chars like x for soup and q for deserts. I tried

```
Using Console.ReadLine()[0]
Using Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
Using Char.TryParse()
Using Convert.ToChar()
```

but couldn't make it. Is there anyone to help me to understand that?

Comment: In general, `ftype[0]` will give you the first character of the string. You say only "couldn't make it", we'd need to know what happened when you tried using this to tell you how to improve it. Did you fix the dictionary so that `x` *actually* means soup? Because right now `1` means soups, not `x`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when you say fix the dictionary i get the problem.. it is even enough for me to get the solution. thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get the results from the dictionary, you'll need to understand how a dictionary works.
A dictionary is a key:value pair.
So if you want desserts to be q, you'll need to edit the "4" as that is the key and then change it to q.

```
var foodTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foodTypeMap["x"] = "Soups";
    foodTypeMap["y"] = "Vegetables";
    foodTypeMap["m"] = "Mains";
    foodTypeMap["q"] = "Deserts";
        
   var PickFromDictionary = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(foodTypeMap[PickFromDictionary]);
```

this code will run and if you type x,y,m or q you'll get one of the dishes.

```
foodTypeMap["x"] = "Soups";
```

i changed the Key value to an x, so instead of 1, if you now input an x you'll get the "Soups" and i changed the other values to some other chars, too.

if you type something that's not in the dictionary you'll get an exception